# passing function arguments in elisp

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have a function defined in my `init.el`:

```
(defun bind-key (keymap)
    (evil-define-key '(normal insert) keymap (kbd "C-=") 'some-function))

(bind-key 'c++-mode-map)
```

But `evil-define-key` does not bind the `C-=` to some-function in `keymap`.

However, invoke `evil-define-key` directly is ok:

```
(evil-define-key '(normal insert) c++-mode-map (kbd "C-=") 'some-function)
```

I have tried:

```
(bind-key 'c++-mode-map)
```

```
(bind-key c++-mode-map)
```

Neither works.

I have googled for passing keymaps to a function, but found no solution. Then, I noticed `evil-define-key` is a macro. But I can not found solutions in this situation.

How can I get `bind-key` to work? By passing a keymap to it, the function binds `C-=` to some-function in in the keymap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, this is trickier than it looks because `evil-define-key` is a macro (defined [here](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/3766a521a60e6fb0073220199425de478de759ad/evil-core.el#L974)). It takes a symbol that names a keymap variable, and binds the key once that variable has been defined. However, in this case it gets the symbol `keymap` instead of `c++-mode-map`, since a macro invocation receives as arguments the literal values in the call.

You can get around this by changing your own function into a macro.  That means that instead of just running some code, it needs to return some code that then gets evaluated.  Like this:

```
(defmacro bind-key (keymap)
  `(evil-define-key '(normal insert) ,keymap (kbd "C-=") 'some-function))
```

The backquote introduces a form that gets returned verbatim, except for values inside it preceded by a comma.

Invoke it with `(bind-key c++-mode-map)`, and it should be equivalent to your explicit call to `evil-define-key`.

Comment: Thanks, define bind-key as macro solves the problem.